# Crystal Report Error 'Load Report Failed' after hosting with windows server

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

Getting error '**Load Report Failed**'. tried all solutions. At localhost it's working fine but when i hosting my web application with windows server getting error '**Load Report failed**', my hosting provider updated their OS to Windows 2012 before update my all reports were working fine.(getting error with all reports)

Comment: Trying debugging using the browser and post the error here

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes:

1. Crystal report need in your project properties to copy if newer.
2. Check crystal report file if exists in our project deployment folder.
3. Check Crystal Report file directory if it is copied in the right directory folder in Server PC like as your project Dev PC.